# Install GSL to a different directory

Tags: installation, gnu, gsl

I'm encountering a problem when installing the GNU scientific library (GSL) on a shared computer cluster. I am able to configure and make gsl no problem, but when I run the command 'make install' it's not able to make the folder /usr/local/include/gsl (because I lack the requisite permissions to influence shared spaces).

How I can install gsl within a different directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this when you run the configure script. Your installation procedure would then be:

```
./configure --prefix=$PATH_TO_WHERE_YOU_WANT_TO_INSTALL_GSL
make
make install
```